# How to save response in static resource to call that response in web service Test Class?

Tags: unit-test, webservices

I'm getting the flowing error in Webservice test class.

```
Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts?
```

I think in test execution we need to make a callout or I'm not sure what is wrong with test class. After googled about it I came to know that we need to store a response static resource and make a callout like below.

```
 StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
 mock.setStaticResource('myStaticResourceName');
 mock.setStatusCode(200);
 mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

In my actual test class, I am doing like below

```
 test.startTest();
    insert agmnt;
    Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new LeadCreation_Mock());
    NewAssignmentCreation.sendcbp(gm.id, con.id, agmnt.Name,agmnt.Name, con.id);
    test.stopTest();
}
```

Do we need to call response in test class using the static resource? If Yes, Can anyone help me to how to do that?

Comment: Static resource is a not required to set a mock, You can mock something in Apex class itself.  You can jump into the trailhead. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_soap_callouts

Answer (score 3):

```
Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new YourWebServiceMockImpl());
```

SOAP based webservice only supports `WebServiceMock` class.

You cannot use `StaticResourceCalloutMock` to test SOAP based webservices.

Refer [Test Web Service Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm)